# Correct manner in implementing a tables header view using Swift and UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm a junior iOS developer and I'm playing around with a UITableView. As the title suggests, I'm looking for the *correct* way to insert a given view into the header section of a UITableView. I've used the following two methods:

```
tableView.tableHeaderView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("InputToListCell", owner: nil, options: nil)[0] as! UITableViewCell
```

and

```
let nib = UINib(nibName: "InputToListCell", bundle: nil)
tableView.registerNib(nib, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier:"InputToListCell")

override func tableView(tableView:UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section:NSInteger) -> UIView{
    let header = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier("InputToListCell")
    return header!;
}
```

Which would be the better method? If there is even a better method as both of them work or is this a matter of preference? I'm just wondering why have two things that do the same thing? For flexibility?

Comment: I would go with the second option while I have never ever written the first two lines, since when using a storyboard they are not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They do different things.

Your first block will add a `tableHeaderView`  A single view that appears over the whole table and scrolls with the table.

The second block will create a section header that will be displayed at the top of each section in the table.  It will mostly scroll with the table, but it will pin to the top of the screen until the whole section has been scrolled off screen.

So, it all depends on which you're actually trying to do.  In a table without sections (technically with only one section), they are very similar with the difference being that the second will pin to the top of the screen, but the first will not.

BTW, in both cases, the tableHeaderView need not (probably shouldn't be) derived from `UITableViewCell`

Comment: What a spot on answer. Thank you.